# Android MediaPlayer getCurrentPosition returns 0

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using a MediaPlayer to play several audio files.  I have a custom MediaController based on androids MediaController.  The problem I am having is that when I pause the player the controller shows the current position as 0 until I hit play again.  I have traced it down to the media player returning 0 as its position while paused.  Is this the intended behavior?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Have you tried on single audio? If yes, try on other too. And please provide some code you are using.

Comment: I ran into this same issue on a Marshmallow device but *not* in KitKat or Gingerbread. This has caused me a lot of grief!

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be put up a static int that catches the currentposition of the media player before it is stopped or paused.

```
 int currentPos = mediaPlayer.CurrentPosition;

                mediaPlayer.Stop();
                mediaPlayer.Release();

                stopIsActive = true;

                WriteSeekingToDataBase(currentPos, CurrentSongObject);
```